# Ngrok with vagrant doesn't work in windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant, ngrok, tunnel

I'm trying to expose my local server through ngrok. I'm using vagrant to run my project in my localserver so, I read that there is a plugin for vagrant and ngrok, "vagrant share". I already downloaded ngrok but when I run the command vagrant share, this is the result :

> The executable 'ngrok' Vagrant is trying to run was not found
>   in the PATH variable. The 'ngrok' executable is required to
>   run Vagrant share. If 'ngrok' is currently installed in a
>   non-standard location, append that location to the PATH
>   variable and run this command again.

I already put ngrok in the environment variable but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix it? I have several days with this problem and I can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the  `vagrant share` plugin manually?

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-share
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly have ngrok in your Windows PATH. I suspect the `vagrant share` plugin does not install `ngrok`.

To do this same thing for myself, I happened to be running with Visual Studio Code, using PowerShell as the Terminal. I downloaded ngrok in zip form from the ngrok web site, extracted, placed it in my Windows home directory, and added that to the PowerShell path. Then `vagrant share` immediately worked (I did not have to explicitly setup an authtoken or connect an account). Below substitute `windowsuser` with your account id.

1. Download ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip from here: https://ngrok.com/download
2. Doubleclick on it in your Downloads folder, copy and paste it into an accessible folder, like `c:\Users\windowsuser`
3. In Powershell terminal, execute: `$env:Path += ";c:\users\windowsuser"`
4. In Powershell terminal, verify ngrok.exe is now available, like so:

```
PS C:\Users\windowsuser\vagrant_getting_started> ngrok
NAME:
   ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

DESCRIPTION:
    ngrok exposes local networked services behinds NATs and firewalls to the
    public internet over a secure tunnel. Share local websites, build/test
    webhook consumers and self-host personal services.
    Detailed help for each command is available with 'ngrok help <command>'.
    Open http://localhost:4040 for ngrok's web interface to inspect traffic.

EXAMPLES:
    ngrok http 80                    # secure public URL for port 80 web server
    ngrok http -subdomain=baz 8080   # port 8080 available at baz.ngrok.io
    ngrok http foo.dev:80            # tunnel to host:port instead of localhost
    ngrok http https://localhost     # expose a local https server
    ngrok tcp 22                     # tunnel arbitrary TCP traffic to port 22
    ngrok tls -hostname=foo.com 443  # TLS traffic for foo.com to port 443
    ngrok start foo bar baz          # start tunnels from the configuration file

VERSION:
   2.3.35

AUTHOR:
  inconshreveable - <alan@ngrok.com>

COMMANDS:
   authtoken    save authtoken to configuration file
   credits      prints author and licensing information
   http         start an HTTP tunnel
   start        start tunnels by name from the configuration file
   tcp          start a TCP tunnel
   tls          start a TLS tunnel
   update       update ngrok to the latest version
   version      print the version string
   help         Shows a list of commands or help for one command
PS C:\Users\windowsuser\vagrant_getting_started>
```

5. Then `vagrant share` should work; as you can see, I am working through the vagrant tutorials.

```
PS C:\Users\windowsuser\vagrant_getting_started> vagrant share
==> default: Detecting network information for machine...
    default: Local machine address: 127.0.0.1
    default:
    default: Note: With the local address (127.0.0.1), Vagrant Share can only
    default: share any ports you have forwarded. Assign an IP or address to your
    default: machine to expose all TCP ports. Consult the documentation
    default: for your provider ('virtualbox') for more information.
    default:
    default: Local HTTP port: 4567
    default: Local HTTPS port: disabled
    default: Port: 2200
    default: Port: 4567
==> default: Creating Vagrant Share session...
==> default: HTTP URL: http://e058e1d1b464.ngrok.io
==> default:
```

6. If you are using a regular CMD prompt instead, you can set the PATH like the following, and the exact same ngrok and vagrant commands as above will also work.

```
C:\Users\windowsuser>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\windowsuser
```

Answer (score 0):

In your $PATH provide only the path to where ngrok binary executable can be found. For example: `/path/to` is correct , and not `/path/to/ngrok`

At least that was my mistake at first. Hope that detail helps to someone. In principle @learning2learn 's answer is correct.